# Как сделать такие цифры?

Tags: html, css, css3

[Ссылка на картинку](https://ibb.co/CJwdXfH)

Как вот такую сделать?) задаю размер шрифта - просто увеличивается цифра, но не прибавляется жирность, а жирность уже стоит 900, выше нельзя, пробовал через befor что-то не вышло ничего... font-size должен быть 35

Comment: Шрифт у цифр какой?

Comment: font-family: "Proxima Nova - Black"; но шрифт уже нельзя использовать, я уже 2 подключил, будет тормозить от них...

Comment: Этот шрифт сам по себе жирный.Если не хочешь его подключать, то возьми эти четыре цифры просто картинками сохрани.

Comment: картинками тоже не могу, avacode их как шрифт воспринимает и не дает вырезать

Comment: Сделай скриншот и вырежи - делов-то.

Comment: походу так и придется сделать)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
ul{
  padding-left: 0;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}


li{
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: -o-flex;
  display: flex;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

span{
  font-size: 60px;
  color: yellow;
  font-weight: 800;
   padding-right: 40px;
   position: relative;
}
span:after{
  content: '-';
  position: absolute;
  color: #000;
  padding-left: 10px;
  top: -3px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
      <span>1</span>
      Вызов бригады
    </li>
     <li>
      <span>2</span>
     вся бригада
    </li>
     <li>
      <span>3</span>
      длительный срок
    </li>
     <li>
      <span>4</span>
      опыт
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Comment: забыл указать, извините, font-size там 35 должен быть..

Comment: @Andrey S если ответ Вам помог поставте галочку ...

Comment: к сожалению нет, это не решение